# Dúvida classe Random em Java

Tags: java, jpa

Galera estou tentando criar um sistema de números da mega sena. Basicamente eu tenho que ter um cliente(id) que ira gerar 6 números aleatórios.

```
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private int numeros;
```

Eu criei a classe cliente que tem nome, email e numeros.

```
public class Random1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random gerador = new Random();
     
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println(gerador.nextInt(59));
        }
```

E criei a classe random, a dúvida e a seguinte, como eu faço para cada jogo criado de 6 números, ficarem atrelados a um ID na tabela cliente?

Comment: 1) Só pra você saber, `Random1` é um péssimo nome em termos de modelagem de classes, não diz nada sobre o que a classe é ou faz. 2) A forma de gerar está errada, porque está deixando repetir números. 3) Em termos de mapeamento objeto-relacional não faz sentido ter um campo `int numeros`, seria um array ou lista de números com tamanho fixo em 6, e na verdade mesmo isso está errado porque um cliente poderia fazer várias apostas portanto deveria ter o conceito de `Aposta` cada uma com seis números. Pra finalizar, por normalização de BD não convém manter os seis números numa só coluna da tabela.

Comment: Enfim, orientação a objetos é uma coisa, banco de dados relacional outra, ORM é a ideia de relacionar esses dois mundos (que no seu caso fatalmente vai envolver mais de uma tabela e chaves estrangeiras) e pessoalmente acho que deveria ser estudada depois que já tem uma boa noção dos dois primeiros. Mas cada um é cada um. Também uma estudada em como levantar requisitos.

Comment: Sua maior dúvida é gerar os 6 números aleatórios ou é salvá-los no banco de dados?

Comment: @Piovezan Obrigado pelas dicas amigo, como estou me formando ainda, me falta bastante conhecimento mesmo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa isso amigo, eu consigo gerar os números com a classe random, porém eu não conseguir atrelar os números gerados a uma classe cliente entende?

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito mais didatico de resolver isso é assim:

```
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private int numero1;
    private int numero2;
    private int numero3;
    private int numero4;
    private int numero5;
    private int numero6;

    public Cliente(int[] numeros){
        int numero1 = numeros[0];
        int numero2 = numeros[1];
        int numero3 = numeros[2];
        int numero4 = numeros[3];
        int numero5 = numeros[4];
        int numero6 = numeros[5];
    }
}

public class Random1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random gerador = new Random();
        
        int[] valoresSorteados = new int[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            int valorRandom = gerador.nextInt(59);
            System.out.println(valorRandom);
            valoresSorteados[i] = valorRandom;
        }
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(valoresSorteados);
    }
}
```

Mas vale notar o seguinte, para um codigo de estudos qualquer coisa atende, em um projeto de verdade diversos problemas com essa implementação vão aparecer, como por exemplo confiar que vai vir um array de 6 posições no contrutor da classe cliente, por isso é sempre bom tentar seguir as boas praticas de codigo do mercado.
Se isso for so para estudar orientação a objetos recomendo voce remover a parte do banco de dados para ficar mais facil, depois que voce resolver o problema da logica que voce precisa é so salvar no banco, va por partes